# Laravel 5.8 - Authorization works without registering ProjectPolicy in AuthServicerProvider.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-authorization

I am following Jeffrey Way's laracasts from scratch and he mentions registering the ProjectPolicy.php in AuthServiceProvider.php. However, I tried refreshing my auth page to check on some other account without doing so, and it still works.

This is a weird question because I think I'm wasting time on something which works and I shouldnt be worried about.
Below is the code snippet.

Ive tried commenting quite a few LoCs which I thought could be used by the framework to authorize the pages-

ProjectsController.php

```
public function __construct(){

      // $this->middleware('auth'); 

    }
```

unedited version for the question, here. 
show() method in ProjectsController.php

```
  public function show(Project $project, Twitter $twitter)
    {
        // $twitter = app('twitter');
        // dd($twitter);

        // abort_if($project->owner_id !== auth()->id(),403);
        //abort_unless();
        $this->authorize('view',$project);

        return view('project.show',compact('project'));
    }
```

ProjectPolicy.php

```
    public function view(User $user, Project $project)
    {
         return $project->owner_id == $user->id;//works even if I remove this
    }// works even if I remove the complete method.
```

ProjectsController.php

```
public function show(Project $project, Twitter $twitter)//edited
    {
        $this->authorize('view',$project);//the authorization is enabled just by this loc.

        return view('project.show',compact('project'));
    }
```

I am so confused so as to how this is still working.

How is the framework picking up
 `authorize('view',$project);` 
even when Im removing the view() method?

Edit: Found this on the documentations page.

> Instead of manually registering model policies, Laravel can auto-discover policies as long as the model and policy follow standard Laravel naming conventions. Specifically, the policies must be in a Policies directory below the directory that contains the models. So, for example, the models may be placed in the app directory while the policies may be placed in the  app/Policies directory. In addition, the policy name must match the model name and have a  Policy suffix. So, a User model would correspond to a UserPolicy class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to register your policy to fit your model, more informations :

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#registering-policies

In your `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php` file, just add :

```
protected $policies = [
    Project::class => ProjectPolicy::class,
];
```